# Issue in adding M2_REPO variable in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am adding M2_REPO variable in eclipse using `Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Build Path --> Classpath Variables --> New -->` and then providing name as **M2_REPO** and selecting maven repository folder, then I see this variable getting added in the **Classpath variables** list. Then I click OK button.

After that, if again I see the above **Classpath variables**, then i don't find the **M2_REPO** variable there, due to which I am getting `Unbound classpath variable: M2_REPO/....jar` error in my project.

Can someone please help.

Comment: something's just deeply wrong with your eclipse conf, try to create new workspace and repeat. it must save the var in normal case

Comment: right mouse click on project then preferencies->deployment assembly->add-> java build path  and add all maven libs from M2_Repo

Comment: may be I'm incorrectly understand what you need but I think this may be help you)

Answer (score 5):

Check for settings.xml in

> Window --> Preferences --> Maven ---> User Settings

If not, set it there and change localRepository path in settings tag inside settings.xml. Normally you will find settings.xml in .m2 folder under the user folder (for eg. C:\Documents and Settings\userName.m2).

Comment: Then search for settings tag and set your repository path in localRepository. It will be reflected in classpath variable M2_Repo

Comment: Once you set you have to restart the eclipse Juno :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're doing it wrong. If you're using Eclipse (a later version, something like Juno), you shouldn't deal with the `M2_REPO` classpath variable at all. You should adjust your Maven settings by going to Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings. The `M2_REPO` is derived from those settings and you must not override it manually.

Comment: Why must not? You can change the var whether the mvn plugin is installed or not.

Comment: Actually, in Eclipse Juno, if you have the Maven plugin installed, you can't modify `M2_REPO`. It's set as unmodifiable.

Answer (score 1):

My M2_REPO variable kept disappearing as well, the hint for me was here:

http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Eclipse-Plugin-how-to-remove-M2-REPO-classpath-variable-re-post-td3375082.html

I'm running Spring Tool Suite 3.6.2 (which is based off Eclipse Luna).

In my workspace there's a file `workspace-sts-3.6.2.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`

Add the following line:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.classpathVariable.M2_REPO=<your repo location>
```

Restart Eclipse/STS, and the M2_REPO classpath variable should be there again.

Edit: It happened to me again. :'(

The step above didn't work the second time, but doing

```
mvn -Declipse.workspace="(path to workspace)" eclipse:configure-workspace
```

added the M2_REPO variable again.

Comment: If some is still facing the issue related to M2_REPO getting disappeared while creating the new the variable. The solution is to clean the folders/files in the metadata folder and restart the eclipse-sts. Once that is done point to the correct settings.xml file in the maven folder. M2_REPO will appear updated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out that I had a problem with maven. Paste

mvn --version

in your command line. Does it show maven version correctly? If not, then check your system variables : M2_HOME, M2. If they are not set -> set it to the correct maven directory and restart Eclipse. Everything should be fine, M2_REPO will be added automatically.

If they exist and they are set to the correct maven directory, check your JAVA_HOME and PATH variables as different maven versions require different java version. If it's not correct version of java -> set it to the correct one.

This solved my problem for good:).

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause of this problem is the `m2e` maven plugin. If using this plugin, I would suggest to remove it and use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` instead.

[How to remove `m2e`, click here for help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538688/how-do-i-uninstall-m2e-in-eclipse-kepler):

1. Uninstall from Eclipse menu:  About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Installed Software
2. Delete plugin files and folder with name `m2e`  from `plugin` folder in eclipse installation location

Answer (score 0):

The direct form to resolve it:

**mvn -Declipse.workspace="/path/to/workspace" eclipse:configure-workspace**

*Description of command in the documentation:*

> Configures The following Eclipse Workspace features
>
> > Adds the classpath variable MAVEN_REPO to Eclipse.
> >         Optionally load Eclipse code style file via a URL.

-Declipse.workspace 
is a required parameter
Directory location of the Eclipse workspace.
User property is: eclipse.workspace.

Ref: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/configure-workspace-mojo.html