# How do i uninstall m2e in eclipse kepler

Tags: m2e, eclipse-kepler, m2e-wtp

I  just download eclipse kelper  and  found out  the  m2e and m2e-wtp plugins had been installed,and the new m2e plugins has  no "package"  of the  lifecycle,how do i  uninstall it?

=================================================
http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e
this is the update site i used in eclipse juno(now it seems 404 error).

Answer (score 7):

1. Click Help-> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Installed Software
2. Find out your software
3. Click uninstall

Comment: For me, when I select m2e, the uninstall button remains disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Download fresh copy of Eclipse Kepler.
If you want m2e, use this link http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/

many other m2e plugins are old and stopped development.

Comment: This was a great tip.  The url seems deprecated.  Summer 2018 I used http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you wish to get rid of m2e, you need to remove all packages and directories  containing m2e string in eclipse installation's plugin folder. Removing them from workspace doesn't do much good (they are recreated if needed).

I tried this out in Luna and all m2e integrations (plugins and features) were removed...

Now if you still wish to use maven (but not m2e plugin), you just need to create external tool entries for each maven operation you wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

You cant download the java EE version , you have to download Eclipse Standard, and use the update site to select java EE plugins you want, in that case you do not select m2e integration

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Remove folders:

.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core\

.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration\

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12322926/238089)