# How do I completely uninstall Maven M2Eclipse form Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I uninstall maven M2Eclipse plugin from eclipse. When I restart Eclipse, then, it is again check for dependencies, and updates. Why I am getting this?

Any body tell me how to completely uninstall maven from my Windows OS

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why do you want to uninstall Maven? Do you have a way to manage your project's dependencies?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i uninstall m2e in eclipse kepler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538688/how-do-i-uninstall-m2e-in-eclipse-kepler)

Comment: M2Eclipse comes bundled with Eclipse nowadays (or at least with Eclipse for JavaEE developers), there is no problem with that. Simply don't create projects with maven support and you won't be using Maven. The fact that there are Maven plugins installed is not going to rot your computer.